# Closing Page after 5 seconds and redirect

Tags: windows-phone-8

I´m new to WP8 development...

I have a page and I want to close this page by code after 5 seconds and "redirect" to another page.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution here:

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Splash_Screen_with_additional_splash_image_on_Windows_Phone

Works great. Sorry for asking.